OBJ Export Issue - Textures Missing from BlenderKit Materials
I'm having a bit of a struggle with my car model—after exporting it as an OBJ, the textures seem to vanish, and the same thing happens with the GLB format. I’ve been using materials from BlenderKit, and while everything looks great in Blender's Material Preview, it’s a bummer that the textures appear flat or even missing when I bring the file back in. Is there any way to fix this?
I tried exporting to FBX, but unfortunately, the file size is pretty hefty, and it crashes while exporting in that format.
Just to make sure, I re-imported the exported OBJ to see how it turned out, and here's what I'm seeing.

